Iterator in for loop adds one more time when accessing it outside the for loop
Why is i equal to 3 but the last iteration of the for loop says it's equal to 2?
The condition is i < 3 but why is it 3?


let i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  console.log(i, 'from for loop');
}
console.log(i);




i++ increments it to 3. Then the i < 3 test fails and the loop stops.

This is how the for .. loop works. the first time it will check if i < 3 without any increment, if true, it will go inside the loop, the second iteration (and all iterations after the first one) it will first increment by 1, then it will check the condition. Therefore, when i=2 and after logging 2 from for loop to the console, it will increment by 1 so it's 3 now, does 3 < 3 ? No, hence, exit the loop and print the current value of i which is 3.

For reference, here's the spec description for implementation of The for statement — the afterthought expression is evaluated at the end of each loop iteration.

think about this the i++ comes became the bool check of i < 3
so when i = 2 and the iteration end's the i++ means now that i = 3
then the for loop ask if i < 3 and 3 < 3 it's false then it's stop
try to debug it.
